# Intellij Error running 'JBoss Remote': Unable to connect

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

Trying to deploy WAR to Wildfly 10 remotely with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2. When I run, I get the error:

```
Error running 'JBoss Remote': Unable to connect to the www.example.com:9990,
reason: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException:
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053:
Could not connect to remote+http://www.example.com:9990. The connection failed
```

When I manually go to `http://www.example.com:9990` I get Wildfly console. I can telnet to my site on port 9990 and get HTTP response.

I have checked on SO. The answers did not help me.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, Wildfly versions were different on local machine and remote machine. They need to be the same.

Comment: Had the same issue on Mac after brew decided to upgrade my wildfly 10.1.0 to version 11.

Comment: I have same issue but my version is same on local and remote server. any other idea?

Comment: As said; I appreciate quick comebacks!