# IntelliJ IDEA remote debugging failure - ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, jboss6.x

I want to be able to debug our Java webapp by remotely connecting to a JBoss EAP 6.4 server.  My first attempt is to have the "remote" JBoss running on my local host.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382554/intellij-error-running-jboss-remote-unable-to-connect).  In both of our cases, we get a connection error. Mine is:

> Unable to connect to the cse-webdav.com:9990, reason:
> com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException:
> java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not
> connect to remote://cse-webdav.com:9990. The connection timed out

(cse-webdav.com is an alias for my localhost, set up in my `hosts` file.)  I can successfully log in to http://cse-webdav.com:9990 using my (Chrome) web browser, and get the admin console as expected.  My IntelliJ settings are:

[image]

The other question I referenced earlier has an answer that says that problems can occur due to version mismatches in the JBoss settings.  In the image, there appears to be such a mismatch between versions 6.4 and 7.5.  However, IntelliJ automatically chose the version (7.5) based on my entry of the JBoss Home directory, and I can't seem to change it.

[image]

How can I configure my IntelliJ to connect to JBoss.  It seems like it should be easy, but it hasn't been.

Comment: Do you have the same JBoss versions installed locally and on the remote server?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - my "remote server" *is* my local server.  (I'm doing that to simplify the determination of the debugging set up.)

Comment: If you can reproduce it with a clean JBoss installation, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the exact steps/configuration/sample project.